# What is the probability of grabbing two socks of the same color when selecting three socks at random from the drawer?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I have the following problem which I am trying to resolve using two methods, but I am getting two different answers.

In a drawer there are $14$ black socks, $11$ blue and $10$ white. You grab $3$ at random, what is the probability of having two of the same color?

Method 1: calculating the probability as:
$P(A)=1-P(B)$

Where P(B) is the probability of not having a sock of each color.

I am doing this like this:
$$P(B)=\frac{14\times11\times10\times3!}{35\times34\times33}$$

This gives $P(A)=0.765...$

Method 2: calculating $P(A)$ directly:

$$P(A)=\frac{14\times13\times33+11\times10\times33+10\times9\times33}{35\times34\times33}$$

This gives a result of around $0.32$.

So, obviously there is something terribly wrong, but I am not spotting it.

Comment: The probability of having at least two black socks is $$\frac{\binom{14}{3} + \left[ ~\binom{14}{2} \times \binom{21}{1} ~\right]}{\binom{35}{3}}.$$  This is one of those situations where it is easier to have **order of selection** construed to be irrelevant.  Naturally, this construance must be consistently applied in both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Your probability of P(A) is not equal to 1-P(B) because you need to subtract more than just all 3 socks are different color you need to also subtract 3 socks are same color too

Comment: @Bobas_Pett Interesting and arguable point, depending on whether the OP's (i.e. original poster's) use of the phrase "two of the same color" is intended to signify $~\color{red}{\text{at least two}}~$ or $~\color{red}{\text{exactly two}}.$

Comment: @user2661923 I agree, I assumed from his P(A) calculation that he wanted exactly 2. Otherwise the complement calculation should be fine... But I think order is not taken into consideration on his 2nd calculation though

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly 2 of the same color just subtracting the probability of having all different colors isn't sufficient. The general way of approaching these problems is the hypergeometric.  $$\frac{{14 \choose 2}{21 \choose 1}+{11 \choose 2}{24 \choose 1}+{10 \choose 2}{25 \choose 1}}{{35 \choose 3}}$$

Using your complement method:
$$1-(\frac{14\times13\times12}{35\times34\times33}+\frac{11\times10\times9}{35\times34\times33}+\frac{10\times9\times8}{35\times34\times33}+\frac{3!(14)(11)(10)}{35\times34\times33})\approx.67$$

Using your direct method:
$$\frac{({3 \choose 2}14\times13\times21)+({3 \choose 2}11\times10\times24)+({3 \choose 2}10\times9\times25)}{35\times34\times33}\approx.67$$

Gives the same answer